# Store spss data on SQL database based on uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, database, spss

I Imported a table from SQL database to SPSS dataset, I edited the table by adding a new column to it after some statistics, but when I try to export the table back to the database by adding the new column, by matching the Primary key from dataset and database table which is of type "uniqueIdentifier, this error is shown to me

```
> Error # 6492 
>The ODBC subsystem has issued an error which prevents the processing of SAVE 
>TRANSLATE ODBC request. 
>Execution of this command stops. 
>[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when 
>converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uniqueidentifier is probably a type that the ODBC driver doesn't know how to convert to as it is probably a database internal type.  Try writing your data to a new table without converting and then do an update of the database table from within the database converting the identifier type inside the database.  You can put the necessary SQL in your SAVE TRANSLATE syntax using its SQL subcommand.